# Как передать данные для кнопки Like у facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Описание, изображение. Вариант с meta-тегами не подходит, так как в окне может отображаться две кнопки: одна для лайка сайта, вторая для статьи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну не знаю, но как вариант все же подставлять всегда нужную картинку, то можно сделать скриншот, "записать в картинку", а потом подставлять с помощью каждый раз для необходимой статьи

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.site.ru/images/screen.jpg" />
```

Проверяем с помощью https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

P.S. Не совсем понятно, чем именно не устраивает meta-тег. Опишите подробно, что именно необходимо.

Comment: @void в том что вот шапка сайта, которая вида всегда. Она имеет like-кнопку для того чтобы залайкать сайт.
Если открыть статью, то помимо like в шапке, будет like для статьи